# plotting coordinates on the global map

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

i want to plot the three coordinates point on the global map along with the axis values.

The coordinates and the cities name are as follows:

```
lat      lon         name
17.38   74.48        STA
-25.02  25.60        STB
44.586  -123.305     STC
```

My trial script is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from itertools import chain

def draw_map(m, scale=0.2):
    m.shadedrelief(scale=scale)
    
    # lats and longs are returned as a dictionary
    lats = m.drawparallels(np.linspace(-90, 90, 13))
    lons = m.drawmeridians(np.linspace(-180, 180, 13))

    # keys contain the plt.Line2D instances
    lat_lines = chain(*(tup[1][0] for tup in lats.items()))
    lon_lines = chain(*(tup[1][0] for tup in lons.items()))
    all_lines = chain(lat_lines, lon_lines)
    
    # cycle through these lines and set the desired style
    for line in all_lines:
        line.set(linestyle='-', alpha=0.3, color='w')
        
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
m = Basemap(projection='ortho', resolution=None, lat_0=0, lon_0=0)
m.bluemarble(scale=0.5);
draw_map(m);

##########coordinate plotting#############
a, b = m(17.38, 74.48)
plt.plot(a, b, 'ok', markersize=5)
plt.text(a, b, ' STA', fontsize=12);


c, d = m(-25.02, 25.60)
plt.plot(c, d, 'ok', markersize=5)
plt.text(c, d, ' STB', fontsize=12);



e, f = m(44.586, -123.305)
plt.plot(e, f, 'ok', markersize=5)
plt.text(e, f, ' STC', fontsize=12);

##########################################


plt.show()
```

But this script doesnot plot all the coordinates instead some it plots wrong places as depicted in the below figure

[image] additionally it doesnot plot axis values.I hope experts may help me overcoming this problem.

Comment: What's the point of [deleting your identical post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69999414/revisions) and then posting the same question again? Probably review https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303634/what-is-the-accepted-method-of-renewing-interest-in-a-question

Comment: as i had not added out put i deleted it

Comment: As explained in the linked meta question, the normal procedure would be to edit the original question, not to vandalize it and delete it.

Comment: sorrry, for my mistake...next time onwards i will not do